# PowerShell + Excel - $workbook.save() hangs up on me

Tags: excel, powershell

I started messing around with Excel on PowerShell, specially because I had to go through 138 files changing every instance of `$B$1` to `TEXT($B$1,"0000")` and I didn't want to do that manually.

Found a couple of resources online and changed the formula but when I try `.Save()`, PowerShell seems to just sit there, waiting for something I have no idea what.

```
PS C:\> $excel = New-Object -com Excel.Application
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem '\\UNC\Path\to\folder' <Common file string>*.xls -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1 | % {
>> $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($_.Fullname)
>> $workbook.Save()
>> }
```

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: I would be curious to see your code about how you create your object. Do you have alerts disabled? Is excel visible? have a look at this http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/01/31/how-can-i-make-changes-to-and-then-re-save-an-existing-excel-spreadsheet.aspx

Comment: Updated with the initial code

Comment: My guess is that Excel is prompting you for information. Set displayalerts to false might help. Also could set Excel to be visible so you can see the action.

Comment: would you care to redo that comment as an answer? problem was that damn compatibility check popup. Once I set displayalerts to false, it worked as intended! Thanks @Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Excel hangs in this regard I would suspect it is waiting for you to do something. The easiest was to confirm this is setting the visibility to True.

```
$excel.Visible = $true
```

That would just show you the dialog that was hidden from you previously. As discussed in comments it appears you got a message from the Compatibly Checker. Once you know what it is and are willing to suppress it then just have the following

```
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.displayAlerts = $false
```