# Unable to change formula on a cell?

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-formula

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658286/powershell-excel-workbook-save-hangs-up-on-me), I'm trying to replace `$B$1` to `TEXT($B$1,"0000")` on all formulas I can find on a lot of workbooks. Now that i'm past that .save() problem, I've got another (which should've been the first, actually): I can't seem to change `.Formula` value, no matter what I try.

```
PS C:\> $Search.Formula = $Search.Formula -replace '\$B\$1','TEXTO($B$1,"0000")'
Exceção ao definir "Formula": "Exceção de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ $Search.Formula = $Search.Formula -replace '\$B\$1','TEXTO($B$1,"0000")'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValueTI
```

Formula is:

```
=PROCV(("A"&ANO($A6)&"M"&MÊS($A6)&"P"&$B$1);BASE!$A:$P;9;FALSO)
```

In English, if I remember the correlation correctly:

```
=VLOOKUP(("A"&YEAR($A6)&"M"&MONTH($A6)&"P"&$B$1);BASE!$A:$P;9;FALSE)
```

The expected output would be

```
=VLOOKUP(("A"&YEAR($A6)&"M"&MONTH($A6)&"P"&TEXT($B$1,"0000"));BASE!$A:$P;9;FALSE)
```

Comment: You need to show us more code. How is `$search` defined? An English version of the error would also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of things going on with what you supplied. At first glance, you seem to be using the backslash for an escape character to make the dollar signs literal. The escape character for this in PowerShell is the back-tick or grave (e.g. `).

If I was performing this action within Excel, I would probably just Find & Replace every `$B$1` on the worksheet with `text($B$1, "0000")`. Seems to me that it is powerful enough to take care of the operation without PowerShell's `-replace` method. The worksheet method does depend somewhat on `$B$1` begin available but since it is also in the replacement, you pretty much need to know what you are replacing beforehand. Some error control in that area may be necessary if this script is left for casual users.

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath = "c:\temp\example.xlsx"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$excel.Visible = $true
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item("Sheet1")
#set some Find & Replace vars
$what = "`$B`$1"
$with = "text(`$B`$1, `"0000`")"
#use worksheet-wide Find & Replace to change formula
$worksheet.usedrange.replace($what, $with, 2)
#formula(s) should be changed. now Find it and display it
$fnd = $worksheet.usedrange.find($what, $worksheet.range("A1"), -4123, 2)
Write-Output $fnd.formula
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

I've proofed the [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) by finding and displaying the formula after the operations and  made more extensive use of the grave escape character rather than swap back and forth between single quotes and double quotes within quoted strings.

The above code uses the EN-US version I tested with. The actual replacement text for your regional settings would seem to be,

```
$with = "texto(`$B`$1; `"0000`")"
```

Comment: Your replace is probably better since regex was not needed. The slashes were required not to escape PowerShell but the regex engine.

Comment: OK, that makes much more sense now. The use of the plural 'on all formulas' sent me in this direction. It's tried and tested on a small sample.

Comment: ok, first thing I noticed to have done wrong on the question was that I didn't "regionalize back" to EN-US - and so the formula `=PROCV(("A"&ANO($A6)&"M"&MÊS($A6)&"P"&$B$1);BASE!$A:$P;9;FALSO)` would be `=VLOOKUP(("A"&YEAR($A6)&"M"&MONTH($A6)&"P"&$B$1),BASE!$A:$P,9,FALSE)` instead of that mess I've left there.

Second, yeah, it seems like an overkill solution - if this was to be done on only one or a couple files - but I have over 100 of those =p

I'll try this out monday and let you know the result!

Comment: Yeah.. it doesn't seem to be working, @Jeeped =( $fnd.formula still retrieves a $B$1 result, not the replaced "text" wanted =(